# Migrating from PHP (Zend) To Java (Spring with BlazeDS) an AMF Service

Tags: spring, zend-framework, blazeds, amf

Previously we were using the php framework Zend for the backend of our flash application.
We want to migrate this backend to our Java server.
We are using Spring so I guess the easy way to do it is to use BlazeDS since the integration with Spring is already done.

I am not sure but  feel like BlazeDS is also a solution on the client side. My client is already done and send/receive specific objects at specific URL using the AMF format.

Is it possible/easy to develop a service with BlazeDS that have to respect this format?

Comment: I think you should have no problems in migrating. For 2 (personal) reasons: I consider java better then php, and spring better then zend.

Comment: Is that a troll?? I also prefer Java but that doesn't mean that the architecture used by Zend_AMF is compatible with the BlazeDS one...

Comment: your question "Is it possible/easy to develop a service with BlazeDS that have to respect this format?" My Answer: "YES" ! what zend_amf architecture ... ?

Comment: My question is more "Do Zend_AMF and BlazeDS are very different on how the service are called?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully migrated a part of my service.

Actually, once Blaze DS is correctly configured it is pretty straight forward.

For the moment, the only differences I have noticed between Zend_AMF and Blaze DS is how the variable types are mapped (e.g for an integer Zend_AMF sends it as a Number while Blaze DS sends it as an int) and how the class names are sent (in Zend_AMF we use to have a mapping to map all classes names while Blaze DS sends the fully qualified name).

Hopefully it is not hard for me to modified the ActionScript code to map the java classes, so that won't be a big deal.